# if we have 1 to 6 job in pipeline and want to execute 6th job how can we do that

Tags: jenkins, pipeline

in Devops engineering  interview i was asked that if we have 1 to 6 job in pipeline and want to execute 6th job how can we do that? can anyone tell me the correct answer of this question .

Answer (score 1):

There are different way to skip all other stages and only execute 6th stage. one way using `when expression`. This is most widely used to skip other stages based on some condition.

Answer (score 1):

To skip jobs in Jenkins we can use when condition to a stage of the pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent any 
  stages {
    stage ('1 choice') {
      when {
                expression { choice == '1'}
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Choice 1!"
            }
    }
    stage ('2 choice') {
      when {
                expression { choice == '2'}
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Choice 2!"
            }
    }
   stage ('3 choice') {
      when {
                expression { choice == '3'}
            }
            steps {
                echo "Hello, Choice 3!"
            }
        }
  }
}
```